# Is there popularity (sales not income) track on a patent

Tags: prior-art

If there is a patent on a certain product...and 3 yrs later a similar protuct is pattented..is there a way to see how many of the first patented product sold in the previous years..prior to the new patent? Or it was even in the market?

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is not collected by the USPTO or most other patent offices.

The only exception I can think of is India, which requires annual statements of working to be submitted. These reports include details about how many of the products have been manufacturer or imported into India, and they may be published. [S S Rana & Co](http://www.ssrana.in/Intellectual%20Property/Patents/Patents-Working-of-Patented-in-India.aspx) sets out some further details. However, given the relative lack of use of the Indian patent system in most fields, and given this only applies to one country, I'm not sure this would be a very useful solution overall.

Of course, presumably, the businesses themselves would collect these statistics for their own internal use. I can't imagine they would be willing to share this information at all, but it's not impossible.